Qemu qcow2 image not recognized after copy from macOS to Windows for s390x (works with riscv64 and ppc64)
Using qemu 9.0.2 on macOS (arm64), I have 3 working VM's using riscv64, ppc64 and s390x architectures. Each of the 3 VM's uses one disk image in qcow2 format. I copy all files and scripts on a Windows 11 machine (x64) with qemu v9.1.0-rc2. The same qemu commands as used on macOS work correctly on Windows for riscv64 and ppc64. However, the qemu-system-s390x command fails with "Image is not in qcow2 format".
Note the following:

The disk image file for s390x is identical on macOS and Windows (same sha256sum).
The principle of copying qcow2 files from macOS to Windows works for riscv64 and ppc64, not for s390x.
On Windows, the disk image for s390x is correctly identified as qcow2 by qemu-img (see below).

$ qemu-img info disk.qcow2
image: disk.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 30 GiB (32212254720 bytes)
disk size: 16 GiB
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    compression type: zlib
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
    extended l2: false
Child node '/file':
    filename: disk.qcow2
    protocol type: file
    file length: 16 GiB (17141137408 bytes)
    disk size: 16 GiB

Needless to say that I could't find any useful hint online. Any idea of what's going wrong and how to reuse the s390x disk image on Windows?
The guest OS are Ubuntu 24.04 on riscv64 and s390x, Debian sid on ppc64. However, the error occurs well before booting the guest OS. So, the guest OS doesn't matter.
For the record, here are the 3 qemu commands. They are identical on macOS and Windows. The difference in parameters are due to the differences in system architectures.
qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -smp 8 -m 8192 -nographic \
    -bios fw_jump.bin -kernel u-boot.bin \
    -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net \
    -netdev user,id=net,hostfwd=tcp::2233-:22 \
    -drive file=disk.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=virtio \
    -device virtio-rng-pci

qemu-system-ppc64 -smp 8 -m 8192 -nographic \
    -drive file=disk.qcow2,format=qcow2 \
    -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::2299-:22

qemu-system-s390x -machine s390-ccw-virtio -cpu max,zpci=on -smp 8 -m 8192 -nographic \
    -drive file=disk.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,cache=none \
    -device virtio-blk-ccw,devno=fe.0.0002,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 \
    -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::2288-:22

Exact error of qemu-system-s390x on Windows:
$ qemu-system-s390x -machine s390-ccw-virtio -cpu max,zpci=on -smp 8 -m 8192 -nographic \
    -drive file=disk.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,cache=none \
    -device virtio-blk-ccw,devno=fe.0.0002,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 \
    -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::2288-:22
C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-s390x.exe: -drive file=disk.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,cache=none: Image is not in qcow2 format


Did you build your own qemu-system-s390x on Windows, or is this somebody else's ? (Stab in the dark -- was it built with clang? If so, try building it with gcc: clang gets some packed struct layouts wrong and maybe s390 ccw runs into that.)

@PeterMaydell, I downloaded the Stefan Weil's binaries, as recommended by https://www.qemu.org/download/#windows
